# What is the advantage of using Theme.MaterialComponents instead of Theme.AppCompat?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

Reference link, under "Updated Material Style" (for FAB): https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/

From the above link: "Using `FloatingActionButton` with an updated Material theme (Theme.**MaterialComponents** not Theme.**Material**) will provide the correct updated Material styles to your floating action buttons by default."

My app target API level 14 to 28.

Should I create `themes-v21.xml` for `Theme.MaterialComponents`?

Is there any advantage (currently or planned in the future) for using that instead of AppCompat?

Is one inclusive of the other?

Comment: Could you please unmark as duplicate? as said, this is about the updated Material theme (Theme.MaterialComponents not Theme.Material like in the duplicate question)

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod this is not a duplicate.